# Execution flow in cocos2d-X

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am newbie in cocos2d-x.I want to know the execution flow.After searching many websites and forums,still I am unable to understand that from where actual execution starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the classes are in the Classes directory of the project.

In the AppDelegate class you define the initial scene of the game through a Director instance. For example:

```
// create a scene. it's an autorelease object
auto scene = MainMenuScene::createScene();

// run
director->runWithScene(scene);
```

Then in the init function of each Scene you can add a callback to allow calling a function when an event happens. For example:

```
auto playItem = MenuItemImage::create("MainMenuScreen/Play_Button.png", "MainMenuScreen/Play_Button.png", CC_CALLBACK_1(MainMenuScene::GoToGameScene, this));
```

Then in a particular event of each scene you can move to another scene through the Director singleton. For example.

```
auto scene = GameScene::createScene();
Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(scene);
```

You can find example source code at this [link](https://github.com/quanhua92/EssentialsGame-LearnCocos2dx).

Comment: I want to know about main method execution.

Comment: The main is the not cross-platform part that is handled in the directories proj.osname. For example in directory proj.android/jni/hellocpp you can find the main for the Android platform. It does nothing more than initializing the AppDelegate class. Reference directory is for example here (https://github.com/quanhua92/EssentialsGame-LearnCocos2dx/tree/master/proj.android/jni/hellocpp).